# Boolean Comparison in Django Queryset?

Tags: django

I have a model field defined as follows:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    is_course = models.BooleanField("Is Room a Course?", default= False)
```

Now, I'm trying to find all the records in my database that have a False value for the is_course field.

I try the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
myrooms = Room.objects.filter(is_course= False)
```

What is the correct way to do this/

Comment: What database and version of Django are you using? If you do "is_course=0" instead of "False", does that work?

Comment: I'm using SQLITE database w/ Django 1.2.

Comment: The is_course = 0 is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query is correct. Make sure there are records in the database being queried. Do a Room.objects.all() and examine any for the is_course = to False.

Comment: I actually had the same idea and just did the following:
rooms = Room.objects.all()
category_rooms = [room for room in rooms if room.is_course == False]

This works perfectly.  I have no idea why the query doesn't work!!

Answer (score -2):

I see this problem too (same SQLite + Django 1.2 also). Must be some ORM bug. try running the following statement to fix it:

```
Room.objects.all().update(is_course=False)
```

after that, you should get results.

Comment: This is a bit of a silly suggestion - what if the original poster doesn't want to set that value to False on all his records?